# how to call soap webservice in mule without datamapper

Tags: java, mule, jax-ws, esb

how to call soap webservice in mule without datamapper and input is xml. I am using community addition. & **my input is xml not soap envelope.**

**My wsdl location is** - http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL
**Input is** -

```
 <GetCityForecastByZIP>
   <zip>12004</zip>
</GetCityForecastByZIP>
```

**Flow -**

```
<flow name="callservice">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8081" path="mainData/client" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP">
            <cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="SOAP"
                serviceClass="com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.WeatherSoap" operation="GetCityForecastByZIP"
                port="WeatherSoap" />
        </http:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
```

**Getting error** 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.GetCityForecastByZIP_WrapperTypeHelper1.createWrapperObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)

Request xml:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
  <header>
    <documentType>CEN_ORD</documentType>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <createDate>12/20/14 23:44</createDate>
    <originator>IKEA</originator>
    <timeZone>PST</timeZone>
    <dateFormat>MM/dd/yy HH:mm</dateFormat>
    <currencyFormat>USD</currencyFormat>
    <weightUnits>lbs</weightUnits>
    <linearUnits>meter</linearUnits>
    <priceBuCode>207</priceBuCode>
    <routeBuCode>207</routeBuCode>
    <serviceProviderAbbreviation />
    <serviceProviderId />
    <origin>207STO</origin>
    <destination />
  </header>
  <data>
    <deliveryOrder>
      <deliveryMethod>LCD zone A next day</deliveryMethod>
      <excReturn>FALSE</excReturn>
      <operation>cancel</operation>
      <deliveryType>HDN</deliveryType>
      <totalArticleQuantity>4</totalArticleQuantity>
      <totalArticlePackages>5</totalArticlePackages>
      <totalArticleWeight>203.087752</totalArticleWeight>
      <totalArticleVolume>1.3783</totalArticleVolume>
      <sacId />
      <businessUnit>
        <code>207</code>
        <countryCode>US</countryCode>
        <languageCode>SWE</languageCode>
        <name />
        <phone />
        <text />
        <timeZone />
        <daylightSavings />
      </businessUnit>
      <orderCustomer>
        <priceBu>207</priceBu>
        <orderNumber>192286415</orderNumber>
        <type>LCD</type>
        <customerName>Marcus Gorios</customerName>
        <attention />
        <careOfName />
        <addr1>1800 Collins Ave #15b</addr1>
        <addr2>Miami-Dade</addr2>
        <addr3 />
        <city>Miami Beach</city>
        <state>FL</state>
        <zipCode>33139</zipCode>
        <countryCode>US</countryCode>
        <dayPhone>7866267105</dayPhone>
        <eveningPhone>7866267105</eveningPhone>
        <cellPhone>7866267105</cellPhone>
        <fax />
        <email>ikea@ikea.com</email>
      </orderCustomer>
      <packages>
        <package>
          <packageNumber>100052253628</packageNumber>
          <packageWeight>40.6175504</packageWeight>
          <packageVolume>0.27566</packageVolume>
          <palletNumber />
          <mixedPallet>N/A</mixedPallet>
        </package>
        <package>
          <packageNumber>100052253629</packageNumber>
          <packageWeight>40.6175504</packageWeight>
          <packageVolume>0.27566</packageVolume>
          <palletNumber />
          <mixedPallet>N/A</mixedPallet>
        </package>
        <package>
          <packageNumber>100052253630</packageNumber>
          <packageWeight>40.6175504</packageWeight>
          <packageVolume>0.27566</packageVolume>
          <palletNumber />
          <mixedPallet>N/A</mixedPallet>
        </package>
        <package>
          <packageNumber>100052253631</packageNumber>
          <packageWeight>40.6175504</packageWeight>
          <packageVolume>0.27566</packageVolume>
          <palletNumber />
          <mixedPallet>N/A</mixedPallet>
        </package>
        <package>
          <packageNumber>100052253632</packageNumber>
          <packageWeight>40.6175504</packageWeight>
          <packageVolume>0.27566</packageVolume>
          <palletNumber />
          <mixedPallet>N/A</mixedPallet>
        </package>
      </packages>
      <order>
        <priceBu>207</priceBu>
        <number>192286415</number>
        <createDate>12/20/14</createDate>
        <shipmentNo>100052253628</shipmentNo>
        <departureNo>-</departureNo>
        <departureDate>12/20/14 17:36</departureDate>
        <status />
        <deliveryDate>12/21/15 17:00</deliveryDate>
        <deliveryDateFrom>12/21/15 17:00</deliveryDateFrom>
        <deliveryDateTo>12/21/15 21:00</deliveryDateTo>
        <cancelDate />
        <createUserId />
        <vehicleId />
      </order>
      <orderLines>
        <orderLine>
          <priceBu>207</priceBu>
          <orderNumber />
          <lineNumber>0</lineNumber>
          <articleNumber>20293460</articleNumber>
          <articleQuantity>0</articleQuantity>
          <originalArticleQuantity>2</originalArticleQuantity>
          <articlePackages />
          <articleReferenceNumber />
          <isOutOfStore />
          <receivedDate />
          <storageLocation />
          <receiptDate />
          <moveVehicleId />
          <moveDate />
          <languageCode />
          <number>20293460</number>
          <description>JÄPPLING chr Skinnarp dark brown NA</description>
          <weight>65.0357</weight>
          <volume>0.4357</volume>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
          <priceBu>207</priceBu>
          <orderNumber />
          <lineNumber>0</lineNumber>
          <articleNumber>60100879</articleNumber>
          <articleQuantity>0</articleQuantity>
          <originalArticleQuantity>1</originalArticleQuantity>
          <articlePackages />
          <articleReferenceNumber />
          <isOutOfStore />
          <receivedDate />
          <storageLocation />
          <receiptDate />
          <moveVehicleId />
          <moveDate />
          <languageCode />
          <number>60100879</number>
          <description>TULLSTA S chr Ransta dark gray NA</description>
          <weight>28.6598</weight>
          <volume>0.336</volume>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
          <priceBu>207</priceBu>
          <orderNumber />
          <lineNumber>0</lineNumber>
          <articleNumber>70219137</articleNumber>
          <articleQuantity>0</articleQuantity>
          <originalArticleQuantity>1</originalArticleQuantity>
          <articlePackages />
          <articleReferenceNumber />
          <isOutOfStore />
          <receivedDate />
          <storageLocation />
          <receiptDate />
          <moveVehicleId />
          <moveDate />
          <languageCode />
          <number>70219137</number>
          <description>TROPISK plant 12" tropical plant/assorted NA</description>
          <weight>27.99842</weight>
          <volume>0.1533</volume>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
          <priceBu>207</priceBu>
          <orderNumber />
          <lineNumber>0</lineNumber>
          <articleNumber>20217305</articleNumber>
          <articleQuantity>0</articleQuantity>
          <originalArticleQuantity>1</originalArticleQuantity>
          <articlePackages />
          <articleReferenceNumber />
          <isOutOfStore />
          <receivedDate />
          <storageLocation />
          <receiptDate />
          <moveVehicleId />
          <moveDate />
          <languageCode />
          <number>20217305</number>
          <description>KARDEMUMMA N plnt pot 12 ½" white/asst patterns</description>
          <weight>16.358132</weight>
          <volume>0.0177</volume>
        </orderLine>
      </orderLines>
      <orderComment>
        <priceBu>207</priceBu>
        <orderNumber>192286415</orderNumber>
        <createDate />
        <commentCode>16</commentCode>
        <commentValue>NO</commentValue>
        <commentText />
        <userId />
      </orderComment>
      <orderComment>
        <priceBu>207</priceBu>
        <orderNumber>192286415</orderNumber>
        <createDate />
        <commentCode>MERGED_WITH_ORDER</commentCode>
        <commentValue>NO</commentValue>
        <commentText />
        <userId />
      </orderComment>
    </deliveryOrder>
  </data>
</file>
```

Soap Envelope

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ship="someurl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ship:SendShipmentProcessRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ship:ShipmentProcessRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ship:ShipmentProcess>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:DocumentType>?</ship:DocumentType>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:Version>?</ship:Version>
               <ship:CreateDate>?</ship:CreateDate>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:Originator>?</ship:Originator>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:TimeZone>?</ship:TimeZone>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:DateFormat>?</ship:DateFormat>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:CurrencyFormat>?</ship:CurrencyFormat>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:WeightUnits>?</ship:WeightUnits>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:LinearUnits>?</ship:LinearUnits>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:PriceBuCode>?</ship:PriceBuCode>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:RouteBuCode>?</ship:RouteBuCode>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:ServiceProviderAbbreviation>?</ship:ServiceProviderAbbreviation>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:ServiceProviderId>?</ship:ServiceProviderId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:Origin>?</ship:Origin>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:Destination>?</ship:Destination>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ship:DeliveryOrders>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <ship:DeliveryOrder>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:DeliveryMethod>?</ship:DeliveryMethod>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:SACId>?</ship:SACId>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:Operation>?</ship:Operation>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:DeliveryType>?</ship:DeliveryType>
                     <ship:IsExchange>?</ship:IsExchange>
                     <ship:IsMerge>?</ship:IsMerge>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:MergeOrderNumber>?</ship:MergeOrderNumber>
                     <ship:TotalArticleQuantity>?</ship:TotalArticleQuantity>
                     <ship:TotalArticlePackages>?</ship:TotalArticlePackages>
                     <ship:TotalArticleWeight>?</ship:TotalArticleWeight>
                     <ship:TotalArticleVolume>?</ship:TotalArticleVolume>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:BusinessUnit>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Code>?</ship:Code>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:CountryCode>?</ship:CountryCode>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:LanguageCode>?</ship:LanguageCode>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Name>?</ship:Name>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Phone>?</ship:Phone>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Text>?</ship:Text>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:TimeZone>?</ship:TimeZone>
                        <ship:DaylightSavings>?</ship:DaylightSavings>
                     </ship:BusinessUnit>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:OrderCustomer>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:PriceBu>?</ship:PriceBu>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:OrderNumber>?</ship:OrderNumber>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Type>?</ship:Type>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:CustomerName>?</ship:CustomerName>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Addr1>?</ship:Addr1>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Addr2>?</ship:Addr2>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Addr3>?</ship:Addr3>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:City>?</ship:City>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:State>?</ship:State>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:ZipCode>?</ship:ZipCode>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:CountryCode>?</ship:CountryCode>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:DayPhone>?</ship:DayPhone>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:EveningPhone>?</ship:EveningPhone>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:CellPhone>?</ship:CellPhone>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Fax>?</ship:Fax>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Email>?</ship:Email>
                     </ship:OrderCustomer>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:OrderSource>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:OrderNumber>?</ship:OrderNumber>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Type>?</ship:Type>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:FirstName>?</ship:FirstName>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:LastName>?</ship:LastName>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Addr1>?</ship:Addr1>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Addr2>?</ship:Addr2>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Addr3>?</ship:Addr3>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:City>?</ship:City>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:State>?</ship:State>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:ZipCode>?</ship:ZipCode>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:CountryCode>?</ship:CountryCode>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:DayPhone>?</ship:DayPhone>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:EveningPhone>?</ship:EveningPhone>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:CellPhone>?</ship:CellPhone>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Fax>?</ship:Fax>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Email>?</ship:Email>
                     </ship:OrderSource>
                     <ship:HasPackages>?</ship:HasPackages>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:Packages>
                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                        <ship:Package>
                           <!--Optional:-->
                           <ship:PackageNumber>?</ship:PackageNumber>
                           <ship:PackageWeight>?</ship:PackageWeight>
                           <ship:PackageVolume>?</ship:PackageVolume>
                           <!--Optional:-->
                           <ship:PalletNumber>?</ship:PalletNumber>
                           <!--Optional:-->
                           <ship:MixedPallet>?</ship:MixedPallet>
                        </ship:Package>
                     </ship:Packages>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:Order>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:PriceBu>?</ship:PriceBu>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Number>?</ship:Number>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:IdentifierKey>?</ship:IdentifierKey>
                        <ship:CreateDate>?</ship:CreateDate>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:BOLNo>?</ship:BOLNo>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:DepartureNo>?</ship:DepartureNo>
                        <ship:DepartureDate>?</ship:DepartureDate>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:Status>?</ship:Status>
                        <ship:HasDeliveryDate>?</ship:HasDeliveryDate>
                        <ship:DeliveryDate>?</ship:DeliveryDate>
                        <ship:DeliveryDateFrom>?</ship:DeliveryDateFrom>
                        <ship:DeliveryDateTo>?</ship:DeliveryDateTo>
                        <ship:CancelDate>?</ship:CancelDate>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:CreateUserId>?</ship:CreateUserId>
                        <ship:UpdateDate>?</ship:UpdateDate>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:UpdateUserId>?</ship:UpdateUserId>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:VehicleId>?</ship:VehicleId>
                        <ship:HasOrderLines>?</ship:HasOrderLines>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:OrderLines>
                           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                           <ship:OrderLine>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:PriceBu>?</ship:PriceBu>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:OrderNumber>?</ship:OrderNumber>
                              <ship:LineNumber>?</ship:LineNumber>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:ArticleNumber>?</ship:ArticleNumber>
                              <ship:ArticleQuantity>?</ship:ArticleQuantity>
                              <ship:OriginalArticleQuantity>?</ship:OriginalArticleQuantity>
                              <ship:ArticlePackages>?</ship:ArticlePackages>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:ArticleReferenceNumber>?</ship:ArticleReferenceNumber>
                              <ship:IsOutOfStore>?</ship:IsOutOfStore>
                              <ship:ReceivedDate>?</ship:ReceivedDate>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:StorageLocation>?</ship:StorageLocation>
                              <ship:ReceiptDate>?</ship:ReceiptDate>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:MoveVehicleId>?</ship:MoveVehicleId>
                              <ship:MoveDate>?</ship:MoveDate>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:Description>?</ship:Description>
                              <ship:Weight>?</ship:Weight>
                              <ship:Volume>?</ship:Volume>
                           </ship:OrderLine>
                        </ship:OrderLines>
                        <ship:HasOrderComments>?</ship:HasOrderComments>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <ship:OrderComments>
                           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                           <ship:OrderComment>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:PriceBu>?</ship:PriceBu>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:OrderNumber>?</ship:OrderNumber>
                              <ship:CreateDate>?</ship:CreateDate>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:CommentCode>?</ship:CommentCode>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:CommentText>?</ship:CommentText>
                              <!--Optional:-->
                              <ship:UserId>?</ship:UserId>
                           </ship:OrderComment>
                        </ship:OrderComments>
                     </ship:Order>
                     <ship:HasOrderSourceAddress>?</ship:HasOrderSourceAddress>
                     <ship:UseSourceAddressLookup>?</ship:UseSourceAddressLookup>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <ship:SourceAddressLookupCode>?</ship:SourceAddressLookupCode>
                  </ship:DeliveryOrder>
               </ship:DeliveryOrders>
            </ship:ShipmentProcess>
         </ship:ShipmentProcessRequest>
      </ship:SendShipmentProcessRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call an external web service from your Mule flow and if your input is an xml (not soap envelope) , you can use CXF webservice client ( **jaxws-client** ) :-

```
<flow name="ClientFlow" doc:name="ClientFlow">
   <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="mainData/client" doc:name="HTTP"/>
   <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP">
      <cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="SOAP" serviceClass="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData" operation="insertDataOperation" port="MainDataPort" />
   </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER :-**
OK.. what you can do is simple .. you can create a SOAP request out of your input xml and **post** it to the **external webservice** through **http outbound endpoint**..

for example let my **input xml** is :-

```
    <GetCityForecastByZIP>
    <zip>12004</zip>
   </GetCityForecastByZIP>
```

and let my actual SOAP request is :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:weat="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<weat:GetCityForecastByZIP>
<weat:ZIP>12004</weat:ZIP>
</weat:GetCityForecastByZIP>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now what I will do is, I will create the above SOAP request in my flow and post the request through **http outbound endpoint**

I will extract the value `<zip>12004</zip>` from my input xml in a **variable** using XPATH and put the value in  `<weat:ZIP>12004</weat:ZIP>` of SOAP request by the following way :-

```
<flow name="ClientFlow" doc:name="ClientFlow">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="mainData/client" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<set-payload value="&lt;GetCityForecastByZIP&gt;&lt;zip&gt;12004&lt;/zip&gt;&lt;/GetCityForecastByZIP&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<set-variable variableName="Id" value="#[xpath('//GetCityForecastByZIP/zip').text]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-payload value="&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:weat=&quot;http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/&quot;&gt;&lt;soapenv:Header/&gt;&lt;soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;weat:GetCityForecastByZIP&gt;&lt;weat:ZIP&gt;#[flowVars['id']]&lt;/weat:ZIP&gt;&lt;/weat:GetCityForecastByZIP&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Envelope&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"   doc:name="HTTP" method="POST" address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx" contentType="text/xml"/>
<logger message="Soap Response:- #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Now, let me explain what I did...

See here , I have a input.xml which I set here as payload after Http inbound endpoint.

Now, I extracted the value of Id from input payload using xpath `#[xpath('//GetCityForecastByZIP/zip').text]` and put into the **variable** called Id ..

In the next step I am creating a **soap request** for my webservice where I have used the extracted **variable** Id in it to put in the place of `<weat:ZIP>12004</weat:ZIP>` of soap request ...

And finally I am posting the entire SOAP request over http outbound endpoint ..

This process is simple and you can achieve it easily .. Hit the url `http://localhost:8081/mainData/client` in a browser

Hope this will help you

Comment: Please check my question update. I have make flow according to you. But still getting error. Please help me.

Comment: Ok ..I have changed it again as per your service ...Try my updated answer and let me know if it worked ..

Comment: Hi @Anirban, Yes this will work I know. 
But my actual xml has more then 100 parameters. So this is not good way.
I have done with your first answer for test soap url. In our test webservice has zip code is string type. so it working.
But in my actual xml has many field & that have class object. This now preceed. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: No issue .. if you have multiple fields you can always use an XSLT to create the SOAP request .. you actually need SOAP request to send to the external web service .. so you need an XSLT to map all the field dynamically with your input xml

Comment: Hi @Anirban
Can you please help me out to xslt tranformation. I have updated requested xml & requested envelope.

Comment: Hi @Anirban Can you please help me out to xslt tranformation. I have updated requested xml & requested envelope.

Comment: Sure .. we can help .. but please accept this answer as for your original requirement, the solution is given ... now if you need to carry forward this solution you need to accept this answer and open a new question on stackoverflow  mentioning your input xml and SOAP request .. we will definitely look into it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813052/convert-xml-to-soap-request-using-xslt-transformation-in-mule
I have create new question.

Answer (score 1):

use xslt transformer,by writing corresponding xsl file which forms soap request which will be configured to xslt transformer.

After xslt transformer call http-outbound with defined web-service  address.